# Add value to column and keep the same file format in output

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to add some constant value to column 2 substr($0,11,5). I got the desired output with using a simple code.

Is there other option to do it?.

Input file

```
X  9367      211L  36829.00  47705.001 7561 77761  37260.00  47706.00  48136.001
X  9367     1101L  36829.00  47717.001 7771 79921  37260.00  47706.00  48148.001
X  9367     1201L  36829.00  47729.001 7981 82081  37260.00  47706.00  48160.001
X  9367     2491L  36829.00  47741.001 8191 84241  37260.00  47706.00  48172.001
```

code used

```
awk '{print substr($0,1,10) substr($0,11,5)+60000 substr($0,16,65)}' file
```

output desired

```
X  9367   600211L  36829.00  47705.001 7561 77761  37260.00  47706.00  48136.001
X  9367   601101L  36829.00  47717.001 7771 79921  37260.00  47706.00  48148.001
X  9367   601201L  36829.00  47729.001 7981 82081  37260.00  47706.00  48160.001
X  9367   602491L  36829.00  47741.001 8191 84241  37260.00  47706.00  48172.001
```

Comment: What's wrong with the solution you have. Seems pretty decent to me, especially if this is a fixed-width file.

Comment: What about simple `awk '{$3+=60000;$3=$3 "L"}1' file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditional Awk lacks any built-in facility for handling fixed width fields. Over the years, many have lamented the lack of a [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html) function that would put awk on par with other languages' handling of this kind of thing.

GNU awk, if you have it available, has a `FIELDWIDTHS` variable that allows you to avoid splitting your input by `FS` and instead use .. fixed width fields.

So:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
  FIELDWIDTHS="1 6 8 2 10 11 5 6 10 10 11"
  OFS=""
}

{
  $3=sprintf("%" length($3) "d",$3+60000)
}

1
```

Note that gawk will still use `OFS` to separate the fixed width fields, so you need to set it to an empty string to avoid spacing things out.

Also, if you only really care about the one field, and all other fields will be identical for each line, you could alternately just bundle things together:

```
  FIELDWIDTHS="7 8 65"
...
  $2=sprintf("%" length($2) "d",$2+60000)
```

Also, the `sprintf()` is required because the act of adding an integer to `$3` strips the whitespace which it would otherwise contain. The `FIELDWIDTHS` variable is only used to READ the line, it's not used to PRINT it.  The awkward use of `length()` makes this line adaptable even if the field width changes. If you want it to be prettier, you might just compact that format string to `"%8d"`.

Oh, and in case you're unfamiliar with it, the final `1` is a condition that always returns true, with no statement. It's short-hand for "print this line".

Answer (score 1):

With Perl, you could say:

```
perl -pe 's/^(.{10})(.{5})/$1 . ($2 + 60000)/ge' file
```

BTW there is a doubt in your calculation.
To take an example of the 1st line, you are adding 60000 to 21, not 211, and appending "1L" at the end of the sum.  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

By seeing your desired output I believe following may help you on same.

```
awk '{$3=sprintf("6%06s",$3)} 1'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
X 9367 600211L 36829.00 47705.001 7561 77761 37260.00 47706.00 48136.001
X 9367 601101L 36829.00 47717.001 7771 79921 37260.00 47706.00 48148.001
X 9367 601201L 36829.00 47729.001 7981 82081 37260.00 47706.00 48160.001
X 9367 602491L 36829.00 47741.001 8191 84241 37260.00 47706.00 48172.001
```

Comment: The question had "keep the same file format" in the title, which I *think* means the OP wants his fixed-width fields to remain fixed at the same width. Any time you rewrite a particular field in awk, all whitespace for that line gets collapsed and replaced with `OFS`.

Comment: @ghoti, thank you sir, yes you are right, let me try to write a code in `awk` which keeps the spaces as it is, I am not sure at this point but will try to write it.